# Ruby: Is there a way to get the enclosing Module const of a Class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm doing some metaprogramming in Ruby, and I need to dynamically generate a sibling class inside of a module. In doing so, I want to call const_set on the module, but I don't know which Module constant to call that on until runtime. An example:

Given classes

```
Foo::Bar::Baz
Foo::Quox::Quack
```

I want to be able to call a function like this (oversimplified here):

```
def generate_from klass
  mod = klass.enclosing_module # <- THIS LINE is the one I need to figure out
  mod.const_set("GeneratedClassName", Class.new)
end
```

and what I want to end up with, when calling with `Baz`, is a new class defined as

```
Foo::Bar::GeneratedClassName
```

and with a Quack, I want

```
Foo::Quox::GeneratedClassName
```

The only way I know of is to split up klass.name, then repeatedly call const_get on those strings, constantized. Does anyone know of a more elegant way?

Comment: The only two ways I know of doing it would be the way you describe at the bottom, and including a `get_module` function in every class. But, it feels like there *should* be a way to do this. Keeping an eye on this one...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should get you on track:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
      def initialize
        @nesting = Module.nesting
      end

      def enclosing_module
        @nesting.last
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Foo::Bar::Baz.new.enclosing_module #=> Foo
```

Relevant documentation:

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000441

Comment: This doesn't work (or does something possibly unexpected) with inheritance -- if you create a subclass `Corge::Qux < Foo::Bar::Baz`, `Corge::Qux.new.enclosing_module` will still be `Foo`.

Comment: True. I admittedly didn't test with inheritance, which is why I said "should get you on track", not "is exactly what you need". Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 12):

Got it.
[ActiveSupport](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module#parent-instance_method) has this Ruby extension, Module#parent. It's good enough for my use.

Comment: I found another way that may help you in case you don't want to use ActiveSupport for this only. If you are using Rails anyway, that's no concern though.

Comment: I accepted my answer, since it did exactly what I wanted and I'm using ActiveSupport, but I upvoted Michael's answer since it also seems correct when not using ActiveSupport

Comment: As of 2024 and Rails 7.x parent is deprecated. It's now `module_parent`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for a pure ruby version:

```
  def get_parent_type
    #Note: This will break for base types (lacking '::' in the name)
    parent_type=self.class.name.split('::')[0...-1]
    begin
      Object.const_get(parent_type.join('::'))
    rescue NameError => e
      nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you can use a combination of [deconstantize](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/String/deconstantize) and [constantize](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/String/constantize).

```rb
'Foo::Bar::Baz'.deconstantize.constantize # => Foo::Bar
```

so in a method of the class it can be used like this:

```rb
self.class.name.deconstantize.constantize
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 and Rails 7.x:

Module.parent is deprecated.
It's now `module_parent`:

```
> Auth::User.module_parent
 => Auth

> Auth::User.module_parent_name
 => "Auth"

> Auth::User.module_parents
 => [Auth,Object]
```

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e01d93547e2082e2e88472748baa0f9ea63c181/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb#L34

And, in the docs:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html